# Can't Save User Preferences

Tags: customization, osx

I am unable to save my blender user preferences.

- Mac OS: 10.13.3 High Sierra
- Current blender build: 2.79.0 daily build

When I go to save, I receive an error saying I can't save due to a 'read only' permission. I've manually made sure all users have read & write permissions and am still receiving this error.

I thought about moving my blender folders to a different location (outside the applications folder) but my OS doesn't seem to allow it. It'll only create shortcuts if I try dragging them elsewhere.

I don't have this issue with my PC, so I assume it may be related to the OS?

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I see it says that System locations this can happen. In my case, I've moved the folder to other locations and still have this issue. I am using some custom scripts and a different startup scene. Wondering if either could be interfering with my saving.